# grep 2 words at if statements in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to see if my nohup file contains the words that I am looking for. If it does, then I need to put that into tmp file.

So I am currently using:

```
if  grep -q "Started|missing" $DIR3/$dirName/nohup.out
then
  grep -E "Started|missing" "$DIR3/$dirName/nohup.out" > tmp
fi
```

But it never goes into the if statement even if there are words that I am looking for.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Since basic sed uses `BRE`, regex alternation operator is represented by `\|` . `|` matches a literal `|` symbol. And you don't need to touch `|` symbol in the grep which uses `ERE`.

```
if grep -q "Started\|missing" $DIR3/$dirName/nohup.out
```

Comment: it still doesn't go inside of the if statement at all

Comment: Actually sorry I got it. i put the wrong back slash

Answer (score 1):

You should use `egrep` instead of `grep` (Avinash Raj has explained that in other words already in his answer).

I would generally recommend using `egrep` as a default for everyday use (even though many expressions only contain the basic regular expression syntax). From a practical point the standard `grep` is only interesting for performance reasons.

Details about the advantages of `grep` vs. `egrep` can be found in that [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/601061/what-are-the-advantages-if-any-of-grep-over-egrep).

Answer (score 0):

When you only put the grep results into the tmp-file, you do not want to grep the file twice.
You can not use

```
egrep "Started|missing" $DIR3/$dirName/nohup.out > tmp
```

since that would create an empty tmp file when nothing is found.
You can remove empty files with `if [ ! -s tmp ]` or use another solution:

Redirectong the grep results without grepping again can be done with

```
rm -f tmp 2>/dev/null
egrep "Started|missing" $DIR3/$dirName/nohup.out | while read -r strange_line; do
   echo "${strange_line}" >> tmp
done
```